# Apache Storm Bolts stop processing after reading 1Million messages

Tags: apache-storm

I am using Storm Topology to read from Kafka queue and emit aggregates using a single spout. When I have a single supervisor node, the topology is working fine and spout is emitting fine. However when a second supervisor node is added, the spout stops emitting. I was able to verify that there are two supervisor nodes using storm ui. There are no errors either in supervisor.log or worker log files on both the nodes.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: what version of storm? Is there anything in the logs for the supervisors?

Comment: using V-0.9.3. I see some workers after sometime thown Spring Initialization Exceptions later. Not sure why.